# How can I make thread waits for 1ms in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a certain line, that I want any thread to wait for 1ms before execute it. How can I achieve this please. I'm using the following lines before the line that I wanted but not sure if this is the right thing:

```
try // wait for 1 millisecond to avoid duplicate file name
{
Thread.sleep(1);  //wait for 1 ms

}catch (InterruptedException ie)
{
System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Considering this comment *"wait for 1 millisecond to avoid duplicate file name"* you might want to give more background as waiting is maybe not the best solution in this case.

Comment: Some things to mention: 1) Better do not wait for a time period. Wait for an event to happen. 2) If you do not have an event and taken your comment, you should use synchronization to avoid some conflicts. 3) How accurate has the time period to be? Some more information about your current problem would be helpful to answer this question correctly.

Comment: My script creates test file to save logs. The text file named with the date and time. I used wait to avoid two threads creating the same file name at the same moment. So, if the Program waits for 1ms, this guarantees non duplicate names as the name contains milliseconds.

Comment: @JuryA You could have a separate thread-safe class with a `getUniqueFileName()` method that generates a unique file name with time stamp. Then you can handle the duplicate issue in that class by keeping the last created filename for example - and if the new one is the same, append something...

Comment: Why can't you just put a critical section (`synchronized`) around the code that generates the file, such that multiple threads cannot overlap on that part of the code?

Comment: @Tudor: The file name contains the date and time (with ms). But, what if 2 files created in less than millisecond (with synchronize)? so their name will be same, & one will override the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very few systems have a resolution of 1ms in the `System.currentTimeMillis()` call. If you want to wait until it changes then that is what you should do.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ( System.currentTimeMillis() == start ) {
  Thread.sleep(1);
}
```

or perhaps a little better:

```
private static long lastMillis = 0;

static synchronized long nextMillis() throws InterruptedException {
  long nextMillis;
  while ((nextMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()) == lastMillis) {
    Thread.sleep(1);
  }
  return lastMillis = nextMillis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a even better option without using Thread.sleep() (which creates flakiness especially in tests) --> use **Awaitility** library, specially created to handle asynchronous calls.

here is an example for what are you trying to accomplish:

```
await().pollDelay(1000, MILLISECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> Assert.assertTrue(true));
```

It will check the assert (which is always true) after a delay of 1s.

This library offers solutions also for other scenarios, for example if you want to wait for  method to be executed first you can do:

```
@Test
public void updatesCustomerStatus() {
    // Publish an asynchronous message to a broker (e.g. RabbitMQ):
    messageBroker.publishMessage(updateCustomerStatusMessage);

    // Awaitility lets you wait until the asynchronous operation completes:
    await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(customerStatusIsUpdated());
    ...
}
```

See more usage scenarios on [their website](http://www.awaitility.org/).